# Is constructor a static method of a class?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new in JavaScript. I am wondering if the class constructor is a special class static method. I have such an example:

```js
class warrior {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
  }
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  sayHello() {
    return `Hello my name is ${this.fullName}`;
  }
  static createWarrior(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    return this;
  }
}

let warrior1 = new warrior("Ashley", "Yuna", 25);
warrior1.sayHello();
let warrior2 = warrior.createWarrior("Kris", "Snow", 23);
warrior2.sayHello();
```

If class constructor is a kind of static method, how can I modify `createWarrior` static method to be able to return warrior instance?

Comment: Maybe tangential to the core of your question, but can you elaborate a bit on why using a standard `constructor` doesn’t meet your requirements?

Comment: I don't see any real use case but I am only curious if it is ever possible?

Comment: In `static` methods, `this` refers to the class itself, not to the instance. See [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212). Why not `static createWarrior(...args){ return new this(...args); }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `static` method to return a `new` instance of the class itself:

```js
class warrior {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
  }
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  sayHello() {
    return `Hello my name is ${this.fullName}`;
  }
  static createWarrior(firstName, lastName, age) {
    return new this(firstName, lastName, age);
  }
}

let warrior1 = new warrior("Ashley", "Yuna", 25);
console.log(warrior1.sayHello());
let warrior2 = warrior.createWarrior("Kris", "Snow", 23);
console.log(warrior2.sayHello());
```